# Python method not modifying in place

Tags: python, class, linked-list, reference

I am trying to implement a linked list class from scratch in Python, and am encountering an issue that is probably related to how Python is intended to work, but I would like to make sure.

Here is the basis of my implementation:

```
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, data=None, next=None):
        self.next = next
        self.data = data

    def appendToTail(self, d: int):
        newNode = Node(d)
        while self.next is not None: self = self.next
        self.next = newNode
```

And the class method that does not work as I would like it to :

```
    def reverse(self):
        prevNode = None
        currentNode = self # current = 1
        while self is not None:
            nextNode = self.next
            self.next = prevNode
            prevNode = self
            self = nextNode
        self = prevNode
```

I am trying to reverse the linked list in place, but when I call this method, the list appears to be empty.
I also implemented another version of this method that preforms a `return self` at the end, and the returned list is indeed the correct result I am looking for:

```
def reverseNotInPlace(n: Node()) -> Node():
    prevNode = None
    n = n.next
    while n is not None:
        nextNode = n.next
        n.next = prevNode
        prevNode = n
        n = nextNode
    return prevNode
```

To summarize:

```
# creating a linked list such as: [1 -> 2 -> 3]
myList = Node()
myList.appendToTail(1)
myList.appendToTail(2)
myList.appendToTail(3)

# inverting it not in place works
invList = reverseNotInPlace(myList)
# returns [3 -> 2 -> 1]

myList.reverse()
# returns only the first node of myList()
```

So my question is: is there something wrong with my implementation ? Or is what I am trying to do not exactly possible ?

Thank you very much !

Comment: Please [edit] the question to fix the formatting. Also be aware that "class method" commonly means exactly that: a ``classmethod`` which operates on the *class* (``cls``) not the instance (``self``).

Comment: Assigning to `self` doesn't change the list. Once the method returns, `self` still refers to the original head of the list. Unless you use a dummy node (so that `self.next`, not `self` itself, refers to the first item), you can't do an in-place reversal without modifying `self.data`.

Comment: ``self = prevNode`` just binds the *local* name ``self`` to another values. It does not modify any of the *other* aliases to the instance.

Comment: It might be easier using 2 classes: one for the `node` and one for the `list`. The latter one maintains the head (and optionally) tail pointers. This way, you don't need to modify `self`.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi thank you, I just edited the title. Not sure what you mean about the formatting, but please let me know if my question needs further edits.

Comment: @chepner thank you, that's a very clear explanation, I will try to add a dummy node first then.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp thank you, most implementations of a linked list in Python I found online actually define a class for the node and another one for the linked list itself. I was just curious about why my code was not working as I intended.

Comment: „Not sure what you mean about the formatting“ The code has at least two syntax errors due to incorrect indentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a logical error with your first approach. Your Node class must not have a reverse method. Since reversing a node does not actually make any sense. In fact reversing a link list does make sense.

So it is better divide your code in two parts:

1. Your node class having a constructor to initialise a node
2. A linked list class with functions to append a node to end and for reversing a linked list. Also pass the head of the linked list to both of these functions